# Has anyone ever built omniORB on RHEL?

Tags: c++, linux, rhel, omniorb

I am trying to build omniORB libraries on RHEL 5.5.

I tried running configure with

CC=gcc and CXX=g++ and PYTHON=bin/omnipython

I run into this problem where it complains about

```
gmake[3]: Entering directory `/home/local/NT/jayanthv/omniORB-4.1.4/src/lib/omniORB'
../../../bin/omniidl -bcxx -p../../../src/lib/omniORB -Wbdebug -Wba -p../../../src/lib/omniORB -Wbdebug -v -ComniORB4 ../../../idl/Naming.idl


omniidl: ERROR!

omniidl: Could not open IDL compiler module _omniidlmodule.so
omniidl: Please make sure it is in directory /home/local/NT/jayanthv/omniORB-4.1.4/lib
omniidl: (or set the PYTHONPATH environment variable)

omniidl: (The error was '/home/local/NT/jayanthv/omniORB-4.1.4/lib/_omniidlmodule.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64')
```

So, I tried to use the Intel C++ compiler instead, with

```
export CXX=/opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/080/bin/ia32/icc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/intel/Compiler/11.1/080/lib/ia32
export PYTHON=/home/local/NT/jayanthv/omniORB-4.1.4/bin/omnipython
```

But, now it complains about 
    ../../../bin/omniidl -bcxx -p../../../src/lib/omniORB -Wbdebug -Wba -p../../../src/lib/omniORB -Wbdebug -v -ComniORB4 ../../../idl/Naming.idl

```
omniidl: ERROR!

omniidl: Could not open IDL compiler module _omniidlmodule.so
omniidl: Please make sure it is in directory /home/local/NT/jayanthv/omniORB-4.1.4/lib
omniidl: (or set the PYTHONPATH environment variable)

omniidl: (The error was '/home/local/NT/jayanthv/omniORB-4.1.4/lib/_omniidlmodule.so: undefined symbol: __cxa_pure_virtual')
```

The OS is RHEL 5.5 with x86_64 architecture, and I am trying to build the 32 bit binaries. Would appreciate any insight into this problem.

Comment: Is the mentioned SO in the mentioned directory?  On your first variable listing, did you really not have a full path for the PYTHON definition?  You might also want to send email to the omniorb mailing list if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the magic combination to building omniORB on Linux using Intel compiler.

You see where it complains about '__cxa_pure_virtual' not found, this happens under gcc because it can't find a lib called libstdc++

So, make `CC="icc -lstdc++"` or `CC="gcc -lstdc++"` depending on which compiler you are using . Do the same for CXX (if using g++, specify it at g++)

And for Python, I used the omnipython which is a python1.5, `PYTHON=bin/omnipython`

which means it is looking relative to the omniORB root path.

You can see where it complains about 'wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64', this is because you are trying to link a 32 bit binary using a 64 bit linker.

So, force your compiler and linker flags to 32.

`CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32`

Once done, run your configure

`./configure --prefix=/opt/omniInst --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu`

Run gmake followed by gmake install, and you will see all the binaries and libs under omniInst or whichever prefix directory you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

That's because omniidl is implemented as a Python extension module.
The Python executable you are using is a 64 bit executable, so it
can't load a 32 bit library.

Check this out http://objectmix.com/object/196129-compiling-omniorb-32bits-libraries-64bits-machine-suse.html

Comment: Hey Satish, are you referring to the omnipython?

Comment: I was talking about python but also make sure you use 32bit python and omnipython both. you can compile 32bit python in /usr/local/bin directory and change path according

Comment: Is there a way to check if python executable is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: python -c 'import platform; print platform.architecture()'

Comment: I installed the 32 bit python and passed the path of the 32 bit executable, but I am still getting the same exception

Comment: It complies fine when I use g++ and the 64 bit python